# How to SELECT with several conditions? (WHERE ... AND ... IN (...))

Tags: sql, select, derby

For example: in my database I have 3 tables: COMPANY, COUPON and COMPANY_COUPON.
COMPANY table has fields: ID and NAME, COUPON table has: ID, TITLE and TYPE, COMPANY_COUPON table has: ID of the COMPANies and ID of the COUPONs that they own.

So, in java to get all coupons of the company I use command:

```
SELECT coupon_id FROM company_coupon WHERE company_id = ?
```

And put it into Collection.

But I need something to get all coupons of the company by the type,
something like:

```
SELECT * FROM company_coupon WHERE company_id = 1 AND coupon_id = (SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE type = camping)
```

of course this one is not working, but I'm looking for something like that.

I know that i can get all coupons of the company and put them into Collection and then just delete all coupons that not equals to the specified type, but is there any way to do this process in database by SQL commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `WHERE IN` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM COMPANY_COUPON
WHERE COMPANY_ID = 1 AND COUPON_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM COUPON WHERE TYPE = 'CAMPING');
```

You could also use `EXISTS`, which is probably the best way to write your logic:

```
SELECT cc.*
FROM COMPANY_COUPON cc
WHERE
    cc.COMPANY_ID = 1 AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM COUPON c WHERE c.TYPE = 'CAMPING' AND c.ID = cc.COUPON_ID);
```

Using `EXISTS` might outperform doing a join between the two tables, because the database can stop as soon as it finds the very first match.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what i was looking at!

Comment: @VladimirKraykin All of the answers given should work, and all deserve upvotes.  You can't do that, but for future reference, it's good practice to reward helpful answers by upvoting them (I think you can do this after 500 or 1000 rep points).

Comment: Yes, i would like to upvote them all, but now I just can't.

Answer (score 2):

Use only `one column` with an `IN` operator

```
SELECT * 
  FROM COMPANY_COUPON 
 WHERE COMPANY_ID = 1 
   AND COUPON_ID IN (SELECT COUPON_ID FROM COUPON WHERE TYPE = CAMPING)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what i was looking at!

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want a `join`:

```
SELECT cc.COUPON_ID
FROM COMPANY_COUPON cc JOIN
     COUPON c
     ON cc.COUPON_ID = c.ID
WHERE cc.COMPANY_ID = ? AND c.TYPE = ?;
```